# Displaying an output attribute in the Properties window of the geometry nodes modifier

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am creating a tool inside Blender using geometry nodes.
To display the view frustum of a camera I let the user enter the vertical field of view.
My nodes compute the horizontal field of view (see the tooltip on the group output) which I want to display for the user in the modifier properties, but it is not:
[image]
I realize I want to display a single value, although "output attributes" suggests it's for per-element data. It explains why the socket changes from circle to dotted diamond in my computation of the value, but why on the "To Degrees" node?

I tried different options in the attribute domain selection.

The users could try to find the tooltip in the setup, but it's not very convenient and there are other formats like diagonal fov and zoom value I want to show as well..
When I add a viewer node, it does show the value for each element in the spreadsheet window, but without the name I gave it.

[image]

Is there another way to show these values?

Comment: In Blender 3.2 you could (temporarily) use the `Store Named Attribute` node. This would at least show the name in the spreadsheet.